# Accuracy of maximum likelihood estimators

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

Here's a test for comparing ML estimators of the lambda parameter of a Poisson distribution.

```
with(data.frame(x=rpois(2000, 1.5), i=LETTERS[1:20]),
     cbind(cf=tapply(x, i, mean),
           iter=optim(rep(1, length(levels(i))), function(par) 
             -sum(x * log(par[i]) - par[i]), method='BFGS')$par))
```

The first column shows the ML estimator obtained from the closed-form solution (for reference), while the second column shows the ML estimator obtained by maximizing a log-likelihood function using the BFGS method. Results:

```
    cf     iter
A 1.38 1.380054
B 1.61 1.609101
C 1.49 1.490903
D 1.47 1.468520
E 1.57 1.569831
F 1.63 1.630244
G 1.33 1.330469
H 1.63 1.630244
I 1.27 1.270003
J 1.64 1.641064
K 1.58 1.579308
L 1.54 1.540839
M 1.49 1.490903
N 1.50 1.501168
O 1.69 1.689926
P 1.52 1.520876
Q 1.48 1.479891
R 1.64 1.641064
S 1.46 1.459310
T 1.57 1.569831
```

It can be seen the estimators obtained with the iterative optimization method can deviate quite a lot from the correct value. Is this something to be expected or is there another (multi-dimensional) optimization technique that would produce a better approximation?

Comment: the `reltol` parameter which gets passed to `control()` lets you adjust the threshold of the convergence. You can try playing with that if necessary. I understand the argument for argument's sake, but for real applications where closed form solutions aren't as easily computed, is accuracy to two or three decimal places insufficient?

Comment: Thanks. Setting reltol=.Machine$double.eps seems to eliminate all errors.

Comment: Cool! Glad that helped. As you probably know, you can post an answer to your question and mark it as the right one so others can easily see your solution.

Comment: The problem is I was getting some odd results (equivalent models, different specifications, the estimated parameters didn't match exactly) and I didn't know whether I was doing something wrong or the problem was caused by a lack of accuracy from the optimization algorithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer provided by Chase:

> the `reltol` parameter which gets passed to `control()` lets you
>   adjust the threshold of the convergence. You can try playing with that
>   if necessary.

**Edit:**

This is a modified version of the code now including the option `reltol=.Machine$double.eps`, which will give the greatest possible accuracy:

```
with(data.frame(x=rpois(2000, 1.5), i=LETTERS[1:20]),
     cbind(cf=tapply(x, i, mean),
           iter=optim(rep(1, length(levels(i))), function(par) 
             -sum(x * log(par[i]) - par[i]), method='BFGS',
             control=list(reltol=.Machine$double.eps))$par))
```

And the result is:

```
    cf iter
A 1.65 1.65
B 1.54 1.54
C 1.80 1.80
D 1.44 1.44
E 1.53 1.53
F 1.43 1.43
G 1.52 1.52
H 1.57 1.57
I 1.61 1.61
J 1.34 1.34
K 1.62 1.62
L 1.23 1.23
M 1.47 1.47
N 1.18 1.18
O 1.38 1.38
P 1.44 1.44
Q 1.66 1.66
R 1.46 1.46
S 1.78 1.78
T 1.52 1.52
```

So, the error made by the optimization algorithm (ie. the difference between `cf` and `iter`) is now reduced to zero.

Comment: Please consider posting the modified version of your above code.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting the reltol argument, also consider that you were really doing a bunch of optimizations across one parameter, the `optimize` function works better than `optim` for single parameter cases, that may work better for your real problem (if it is really one dimensional).

Comment: The actual problem is multi-dimensional and in the example I was trying to simulate a multi-dimensional optimization problem, even though you're right that there's really only one parameter... it's just because it was easier to write this way.