# What does reltol really mean in optimization control in R?

Tags: r, optimization, controls

I am trying to simulate with maximum likelihood estimation in R.

In the `optim()` command, if I change the default `reltol`  to `1e-4`, estimators that I get are more close to the true parameters, and the execution time is faster. (Though I get better results, but it really feels bad)

If I reduce `reltol` to `1e-6, 1e-8, or 1e-10`..., the estimators I get are less accurate comparing with the true parameters, and it takes a long time to finish the simulation.

Anybody knows what a `reltol` really means? How does it affect the accuracy of estimation? And is there any way to find a proper `reltol` value in estimation? Thank you so much!

Comment: The default `reltol` , per `?optim` is far smaller than your applied values. Please read the StackOverflow rules/FAQs so you'll know to post a reproducible data sample *and* the exact code you're executing. Without that, we cannot comment on your subjective like or dislike of results you got.

Comment: Thank you Carl. An example would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045131/accuracy-of-maximum-likelihood-estimators/10046149#10046149. what are the pros and cons by adjusting the reltol value?